# PHP, OOP, properties

Tags: php, oop, properties

Could someone help me make query using php oop, here is what I trying but not work:

```
$this -> hashs = DB::select('SELECT * FROM'. $this -> table .'WHERE'. $this-> colRep .'IS NULL &&'. $this -> colCol .'= ?', array($this -> commentHASH));
```

If I use normal variable work fine....

Comment: Wrap your database queries in a try/catch. That way you can easily display what error message DB::select gave you.

Answer (score 2):

In php `.` doesn't put a space between the elements you're concatenating. That'd be a start.

Comment: That would be mistake it same like you put like this SELECT * FROMtablename ....

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->hashs = DB::select('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE ' . $this->colRep . ' IS NULL AND ' . $this->colCol . ' = ?', array($this->commentHASH));
```

Try something like this. And if you are already using prepared statement, why only use it with the $this->commentHASH? You should never concatenate sql queries with php variables, as it is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: But it's not variables from user input...

Comment: It is however a lot better if the variables are not from user input, but the vulnerability is still present in the application.

Comment: How SLQi can be executed if user can't change sql flow?

Comment: Maybe the user cannot make an sql injection, but a programmer would still have the chance to do it.

Comment: Do you have example? My opinion is that, SQLi is inpossible if there no get or post method...

Comment: That is true of a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They do not happen automatically, you have to specify it.